# Why does adding brackets when invoking this function breaks my program?

Tags: c

My intention here was to make a simple program that would output the highest difference between two consecutive elements in an array, and my question is, why when add the "[ ]" in the line marked breaks the program (it works fine if I take them out).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define EPSILON 0.000001
#define DIM     5

double maxDif(double vector[]);

int
main(){
    double vec[DIM]={3,5,7,23,0};
    double result;
    result=maxDif(vec[]);  /* <-- problem here */
    printf("The largest diff between 2 consecutive elements is: %g \n", result);
    return 0;
}

double
maxDif(double vector[]){
    double retVal=0;
    int i=0;
    if(fabs(vector[0]>EPSILON))
        while(fabs(vector[i++]>EPSILON))
            if((vector[i]-vector[i-1]>retVal))
                retVal=vector[i]-vector[i-1];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Because that's not what arrays are used like in expressions.

Comment: It "breaks" for the same reason any other syntax violation breaks your code.

Comment: It's just a syntax error. You use the subscript operator without any index. It's simply not defined in the standard like that (square brackets in parameter definitions don't count as usage of the subscript operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `maxDif(vec)` you passing the array (or more specifically, a pointer to the first element of the array) into the function `maxDif`.  The definition of this function matches this call.

Calling a function like `maxDif(vec[])` is invalid syntax.  An empty pair of braces is only valid when declaring an array (and also initializing it if it's not a function parameter, or if it's the last field in a `struct`), not when accessing it.

Comment: But only if it gets initialized in the same step. Or if it's used as the last member of a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you need to send `vec` as argument. Send it like so: `**result=maxDif(vec);`

Explanation: `vec` is an array, and when you pass it as an argument you pass the address of it. The compiler already knows it's an array so the `[]` are not needed, moreover - they are invalid syntax, as you learned

Comment: "The compiler already knows it's an array..." irrelevant, because the function's parameter is a pointer. What is passed it a pointer that happens to point to the first element of an array.

Comment: @juanchopanza correct me if I'm wrong, but for all I know, sending an array is sending it's address, and that is basically sending pointer to first element. However, when sending sending this way (vec was declared as array), the compiler knows how much space was allocated for the array, so the compiler **does** know it is an array -  it knows how much space is owned by it

Comment: The compiler might know how much space is allocated for the array in `main()`, but in the `maxDif` function all there is is a pointer. All information about the array's length is list in that function.